# How to keep only one node in a "bus stop group" in an Overpass query?

Tags: overpass-api

Bus stops often come in groups of 2 (one for each side of the road) or more (if two lines cross at an intersection). Here the results for `node["highway"="bus_stop"]` for a certain area:

[image]

I'd like to reduce the number of results by keeping only one node for each of these groups. It does not matter which one.

I'll add my current solution below, which is based on the value of the tag `name`. It works, but still it is not ideal (more details in the answer below).

Ideally, I expand the query to filter the results based on a certain 'minimum distance' they should have from one another. Algorithmically, I'm thinking about finding all node pairs that violate this rule, and then eliminate the node with the highest number of conflicts. Rinse-repeat till no conflicts remain.

Why would this be ideal?

- It's reusable, i.e., applicable to many more situations than just bus stops.
- It is not dependent on the quality of the tagged data.

Nice-to-have:

- Some way to include a 'relevance' into the algorithm, so that principally nodes of lower-relevance are removed, even if they have fewer conflicts. This is to avoid removing a central node where removing several peripheral ones would have been better.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of the `name` tag of the nodes. This is the same for all stops in a bus stop group:

[image]

I know this is not a `python` forum and this is not even supposed to be a `python` question, but as I don't know how to implement this in the query language (if you do know, please share), I used `overpy` to filter after the fact:

```py
import overpy

api = overpy.Overpass()
stops = api.query('node["highway"="bus_stop"](53.5, 9.8, 53.6, 10.1);out;').nodes
names = set([stop.tags.get('name', None) for stop in stops])

len(stops) #1593
len(names) #760

(...) #keeping one stop per name
```

Crucially, this only works if all nodes have a `name` tag. For my data set, 5 did not, and all but 1 of them would get deleted. That's no big deal, it's only 0.3%.

However, before going ahead and using this everywhere, I'd like to check if it is universally true. To get a good global cross-section, I checked the situation in the 2 largest cities of 162 countries. I checked both, how many stops do not have a name, and, what's the largest number of stops sharing a name. Here are the results:

#### No bus stops

Out of 319 cities, 70 return less than 11 bus stops. This is a concern for another day and could be addressed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/360338/158505) if you have any thoughts on this.

#### Bus stops without a name

Out of the 249 remaining cities, let's see what fraction has no name. There are some cities where all stops have a `name` tag, and also some where none have a `name` tag. Here are the top and bottom cities in that respect:

```
              city              country  stopcount  nonamefraction
153         Matola           Mozambique        571           0.000
22        Brussels              Belgium       2415           0.000
104          Mosul                 Iraq         21           0.000
163         Niamey                Niger         12           0.000
158      Amsterdam          Netherlands       1302           0.000
50    Pointe-Noire  Congo (Brazzaville)         28           0.000
213         Zürich          Switzerland       1637           0.000
82          Berlin              Germany       3102           0.000
12          Vienna              Austria       2814           0.000
211       Göteborg               Sweden       1152           0.000
..             ...                  ...        ...             ...
9           Gyumri              Armenia         12           0.917
42       N’Djamena                 Chad         17           0.941
241     Montevideo              Uruguay         86           0.942
37        Mandalay                Burma         35           0.943
122    Kuwait City               Kuwait         67           0.955
231    Türkmenabat         Turkmenistan         74           0.973
192         Riyadh         Saudi Arabia         60           0.983
111       Kingston              Jamaica        251           0.988
112   Spanish Town              Jamaica         54           1.000
16   Freeport City         Bahamas, The         32           1.000
```

The statistics show that on average, 29% of the bus stops don't have a name, which is quite a high percentage. Also, in 25% of cities, more than half of the bus stops is unnamed.

```
mean       0.293056
std        0.305008
min        0.000000
25%        0.025000
50%        0.163000
75%        0.500000
max        1.000000
```

It could be the case that this is not a big deal - maybe the bus stops in those cities, in which they don't have names, are not showing up in pairs in the data. But that would be a coincidence.

This is the main reason, why I think using the `name` tag is not a good method to group bus stops.

#### Shared names

There is another potential problem: many bus stops sharing the same name, also, when they are not actually near one another. Here the cities where a name is shared by the largest number of stops:

```
             city        country  maxsharedcount          maxsharedname
63        Abidjan  Côte D’Ivoire           330.0                  Arrêt
139        Bamako           Mali           255.0                  Arrêt
86         Athens         Greece            71.0               ΑΦΕΤΗΡΙΑ
102       Mashhad           Iran            66.0         ایستگاه اتوبوس
6    Buenos Aires      Argentina            57.0     Plaza Constitución
12         Vienna        Austria            39.0           Hauptbahnhof
24     Santa Cruz        Bolivia            38.0        Parada de micro
71   San Salvador    El Salvador            34.0          Parada de Bus
216        Taipei         Taiwan            34.0                     臺北
105        Dublin        Ireland            32.0             Howth Road
53       San José     Costa Rica            31.0  Parada Bus del Carmen
95       Budapest        Hungary            28.0     Örs vezér tere M+H
173      Asunción       Paraguay            27.0                     13
189        Moscow         Russia            26.0           Метро «ВДНХ»
210     Stockholm         Sweden            26.0             Vinkområde
```

There are several reasons:

- Generic name applicable to all (arret, parada, ایستگاه ('bus stop')) or many geographically distinct (ΑΦΕΤΗΡΙΑ ('starting point')) locations.
- Non-unique name given to bus stops based on road they are on ('Howth Road') or line they belong to ('13').

Hope that was helpful in showing my current method, and the problems with it.

For those interested, here is the script:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import overpy

# Get largest 2 cities for each country having at least 1 city with > 200k population.
df = pd.read_csv('source_verification/worldcities.csv') 
keep = df[df.population > 200_000].country.unique()
df = df[df.country.isin(keep)].groupby('country').apply(lambda d: d[:2]) 

api = overpy.Overpass()
df['bbox'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row.lat - 0.1, row.lng - 0.1, row.lat + 0.1, row.lng + 0.1), axis=1)
df['stops'] = df.bbox.apply(lambda bbox: api.query(f'node["highway"="bus_stop"]{bbox};out;').nodes)
df['stopcount'] = df.stops.apply(len)
df = df[df.stopcount > 10] #Remove cities with 10 or less bus stops 

def none_and_max_counts(stops):
    c = Counter()
    for stop in stops:
        c.update([stop.tags.get('name', None)])
    nonefrac = np.round(c[None]/len(stops), 3)
    if c[None]:
        c.pop(None)
    try:
        maxsharedname, maxsharedcount = c.most_common(1)[0]
    except:
        maxsharedname, maxsharedcount = '', np.nan
    return nonefrac, maxsharedcount, maxsharedname

df[['nonamefraction','maxsharedcount', 'maxsharedname']] = df['stops'].apply(none_and_max_counts).apply(pd.Series)
```